# Android. Сохранить состояние каталога /system

Tags: android

Использую VS Emulator for Android
Через ADB изменяю права доступа в каталогe /system
После перезапуска эмулятора все права слетают (изменения не сохраняются)

Как можно сохранить сделанные изменения в системе?

Answer (score 1):

`/system` это директория, где хранятся неизменяемые компоненты Android
системы. Она как папка `C:\windows\`, доступна только для чтения. Т.е. изменять данные и менять права в этой директории нельзя. Здесь находятся системные
приложения, которые встроены в операционку и которые, по умолчанию, нельзя
удалить. Содержимое этой директории формируется во время компиляции
операционной системы.

Comment: Через ADB с правами root я могу поменять в /system что нужно. Проблема в том, что после перезагрузки мои изменения теряются. Вопрос как раз в том, как можно сохранить изменения в эмуляторе. В нормальном телефоне можно сделать свою прошивку и перепрошить аппарат. Можно ли что-то подобное сделать в эмуляторе?